# How to debug ajax proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to create simple crud application with ExtJs6 and Lumen as backend PHP framework. I created extJS app following standard documentation. My extJS is running on http://localhost:1841/ using build in sencha server (`sencha app watch`).

When I changed

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    }
}
```

on

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    },
    autoload: true,
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, operation) {
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                msg: operation.getError(),
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        }
}
```

and added those listeners to my proxy and store objects

```
   beforeLoad: function(store, operation){ // 1st; no data items
        console.log('beforeLoad');
        console.log(store.data.items);
    },
    dataChanged: function(store){ // 2nd; data items populated, controls still empty

        console.log('dataChanged');
        console.log(store.data.items);
    },
    load: function(store, records, success){ // 3rd; data items populate, controls show data
        console.log('load');
        console.log(store.data.items);
    }
```

I hoped to see some `MessageBox` with errors or some messages in a browser console, but there weren't either. Btw, there's nothing on http://localhost:1841/data URL. So, two main question:

- Why my `console.log(..` code and `MessageBox` aren't working?
- Is there a way to tell sencha built in server return some sample json
  data on specific url?

PS: I do `sencha app build` to compile js and then use it in PHP app, which runs on another localhost's port and, obviosly, returns some data on `data` URL. But it's still not showing it in my app. With memory proxy it works fine.

Full store class: https://github.com/jehaby/Cognitive/blob/master/Cognitive/app/store/Personnel.js
Full repository: https://github.com/jehaby/Cognitive/
ExtJS app created here: https://github.com/jehaby/Cognitive/Cognitive

Comment: Sencha built-in server can deliver JSON if you put it into files. If you want to get JSON from api/GetSomeThing, then create a folder api containing a file GetSomeThing with the JSON you want to get. Or even better, debug it with the live backend. I can really recommend that.

Comment: Thank you! I created a file named "data" with following [content](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jehaby/5b327c01a145465cfb4a/raw/28c3eedaa28dc7b00c7fec97fdf169da71dab9eb/data) in my root folder. I can see that webserver returns it properly. But I still can see no data in my app and no error messages from listeners.

Comment: You may want to try `autoLoad:true` on the store instead of `autoload:true` on the proxy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It finally worked! But I still don't understand what's wrong with listeners.

Comment: Because listeners are also case sensitive, namely they are all lowercase as per the apidocs.